# How to check if a collection has a null reference

Tags: powershell

I just discovered that when you apply bool operators on a collection, it acts as a filter on that collection.

So the following will return all elements that are not null:

```
$objectArray = @('a','b','c','d')
$objectArray -ne $null
```

But how can I check if the collection's reference is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trevor Sullivan's `if ()` test forces the `$objectArray` to cast to a boolean.

```
[bool]$null     #is $false
[bool]@(1,2,3)  # is $true  , so it looks good.
```

But empty arrays mislead it:

```
[bool]@()       # is $false , so it's not an accurate test.
```

[image: Example screenshot of testing an empty array]

I suggest `$null -eq $objectArray`:

[image: Example of using $null -eq $objectArray]

NB. It really opens the question of why you *want* to know if it's $null, specifically. Trevor's answer is typical and good enough for any common use.

NB. My answer includes an uncommon, but useful suggestion - when you have a literal value for one side of a comparison, put it on the left if you can.

```
0 -lt $counter
$null -eq $thing
"text" -eq $variable
4 -in $collection
```

It's less common, so looks less familiar, but it's more resilient against PowerShell implicit casting doing something you don't expect.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is test the variable for `$true` or `$false`. If it's `$false`, then it's a null reference, otherwise the opposite is true.

```
if (!$objectArray) {

}
```

[image]

Comment: What about `$objectArray = @(); if (!$objectArray) { 'It''s $null alright!' }` ? ->  http://i.imgur.com/QddEqRv.png

Comment: Good point. it's not null. It's an empty instance of Object[], however !$objectArray returns true.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave Yes. The test says "it's null", but it isn't. So it's not a good test. Other things cast to `[false]` as well - this test would say other things were null, like `$objectArray = 0` and `$objectArray = ""` too.

Answer (score 0):

The following tells you if the reference is null:

```
[Object]::ReferenceEquals($objectArray, $null)
```

Testing if the variable is `$true` or `$false` does not always work because an empty collection will cast to false:

```
$objectArray = @()
if (!$objectArray) {
   'The array is not actually null'
}
```